# Decrypt aes-256-cbc encoded file with iv = 0

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, aes

I have an `input.DAT` file that is encrypted with `aes-256-cbd` method. I want to decrypt the file using php. When I execute the following command from command line, the file is decrypted successfully.

```
aes-256-cbc -d -in input.DAT -out output.TXT -K 00478c54c432b3ca9a98d4a750ea874eba07410ae61834cd5aaac7505f1f5ad4 -iv 0
```

But when I try to use php for decrypting the file using the method

`openssl_decrypt($data, AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0, 0);`

it gives me this error: `openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is only 1 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0`

How can I decrypt the file using php instead of the command line?

Comment: @Topaco can you please write the whole function with all parameters? I have tried several ways but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenSSL statement loads the ciphertext from *input.DAT*. Since neither the *-a* nor *-base64* options are set, the raw binary data is read. The read data is decrypted with AES-256 in CBC mode.
The hex decoding of `00478c54c432b3ca9a98d4a750ea874eba07410ae61834cd5aaac7505f1f5ad4` is used as key and a zero IV (all 16 bytes are `0x00`) is applied as IV.

A possible implementation for the decryption with PHP using `openssl_decrypt()` is:

```php
// Load ciphertext
$file = '<input.DAT path>';
$data = file_get_contents($file);

// Decrypt
$key = hex2bin('00478c54c432b3ca9a98d4a750ea874eba07410ae61834cd5aaac7505f1f5ad4');
$iv = hex2bin('00000000000000000000000000000000');
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
print($decrypted . PHP_EOL);
```

Note that `openssl_encrypt()` generates a Base64 encoded ciphertext by default and `openssl_decrypt()` expects a Base64 encoded ciphertext accordingly. Since the ciphertext read here is raw, i.e. not Base64 encoded, the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag must be set. Furthermore, both sides use PKCS7 as padding by default.

Keep in mind that a static IV (like a zero IV) is generally insecure.